# Localstorage values resetting after re-openning browser on iphone

Tags: javascript, persistence

I'm trying to use localstorage as in http://www.sharonminsuk.com/code/storage-test.html
I've copy / paste both html and Js on my nginx backend server.
I've tried with nodejs too.

On my smartphone, http://www.sharonminsuk.com/code/storage-test.html, works like a charm.
Mine does not.

When I close Safari or Chrome, the data of the first one works when my data are lost, using Local Storage of course.

I've tried Http and https, Nginx or Nodejs as Backend.

Even if it's a the same code, line by line !
I've use integer, text values, the same.
Have you already expect this behavior and how did you solved it ?

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html>

<head>
<title>Test localStorage and sessionStorage persistence</title>
</head>


<body>
<h1>Local storage:<br />
<input type="text" placeholder="nothing currently stored" size="20" id="local" />
<input type="button" onclick="store_it('local' window.localStorage);" value="Store it" />
</h1>

<h1 id="local-warning">___</h1>

<script type="text/javascript" src="/public/storage-test.js"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

---

### JAVASCRIPT

```
function store_it(id, storageArea) {
    var textBox = document.getElementById(id);
    if (!textBox.value) {
        delete storageArea.theirValue;  // don't store empty string, delete it instead
        window.alert('5 effacé  ')
    }
    else {
        storageArea.theirValue = textBox.value;
        console.log('6')
        window.alert('Done : ' + textBox.value)
    }
}

function retrieve_storage(id, storageArea) {
    var val = storageArea.theirValue;
    window.alert('14 retrieve_storage : ' + val)
    console.log('14 ', val)
    if (val != null)
        document.getElementById(id).value = val;
}

if (window.localStorage) {
    window.alert('20 Yes')
    retrieve_storage("local", window.localStorage);
}
else {
    window.alert('24 NO')
    document.getElementById("local-warning").innerHTML = "Note: this browser does not support localStorage";
}
```

Comment: I found something to think about: 
when I hide the direction of my home server (IP address) in my domain name provider, it doesn't work. 
When I don't hide it and the IP address appears in plain text in the browser, in the URL, it works.
But why?

Answer (score 0):

But you can always check first...

```
if(!localStorage.getItem('SomeVar')){

 localStorage.setItem('SomeVar', SomeValue);

}
```

To prevent overwriting after a refresh.

Comment: I've tried but nothing changes.

Answer (score 0):

The answer lies with the domain name provider.
I had to add a line pointing to my server's IP address in "DNS Registration" and delete the one I had written in "Web Redirects".

Strange as it may seem, this has nothing to do with javascript, nodejs, nginx or iphone...